# Prev not working inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the colour of my label when the texbox has focus

```
 <div class="editor-label">
     <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName) %>
 </div>
 <div class="editor-field">
     <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName) %>
     <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName) %>
 </div>
```

This is my javascript

```
  $(':text').focus(function () {
        $(this).prevAll("label").last.css("color", "blue");
  });
```

`$(this).prevAll()` is always empty. But `$(this).next()` and `$(this).nextAll()` has a span

Please help I would really appreciate any assistance

Comment: mind posting on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Just a nit-picky note, it's `JavaScript` not `Java`.

Comment: And another nit-picky point, the **HTML** is going to be way more useful than the ASP (or whatever server side language you're echoing those strings from... ) in helping to solve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this).prevAll("label")` is empty because `prevAll("label")` will look for label siblings of the text box. You should do something like this instead:

```
$(':text').focus(function () {
    $(this).parent("div").prev().find("label").css("color", "blue");
});
```

`next()` and `nextAll()` is returning a span because the following code will be rendered as a span, which is the next element after the textbox.

```
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName) %>
```

Comment: if someone else is looking for a solution to this problem look at Naveed Ahmed below. He gives a full solution. jSang Gives a good explanation. I appreciate your assistance (Both of you)

Comment: rather than `.parent("div")` which returns the elements parent *if* it is a `div`, use [`.closest("div")`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to find the NEAREST parent (or the current element) that is a `div`

Answer (score 1):

You could try finding it using the jQuery attr instead 
something like :

```
$('label[for="FirstName"]').css("color", "blue");
```

(not tested, sorry!)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this as per my understanding:

```
$('div.editor-field input').focus(function () {
    $('div.editor-label label').css({"color":"black"});//Reset color for all labels
    $(this).parent().prev().find('label').css({"color":"blue"});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(':text').focus(function () {
            $(this).closest('div').prev().children('label').addClass("selected");
        });

        $(':text').blur(function () {
            $(this).closest('div').prev().children('label').removeClass("selected")
        });

 </script>
```

please let me know what you think.

Comment: Thats actually a great self-answer... I was just getting ready to comment about using a class instead of `.css()` on jSang's answer... I'd almost suggest you accept your own answer, cause its pretty much the cleanest...